# Inserting into SQL server fails using Angularjs and web API

Tags: angularjs, sql-server, html

I am trying to save data using Angularjs and web API under some conditions or "if statement" or selection from the user . Inaddition to input texts, The conditions are : if the user select first item in first combo box and first item in second combo box the insertion value should be 1. If the user select the second item in first combo box and first item in second combo box the insertion value should be 2. If the user select the first item in first combo box and second item in second combo box the insertion value should be 3. and so on
I am using the post method in angular service. what is the correct code because when debug i got errors, thanks in advance.

HTML

```
<body ng-app="ContractT" ng-controller="crudController">
<br /><br />
```

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="Hide" />Hide <input type="button" value="Clear" ng-click="resetform()" />
    <input type="submit" value="Save" ng-click="save()"/> <input type="button" value="Delete" ng-click="delete(selectedMember.sys_key)" />
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Contract Type</legend>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Code</td>
                <td><input type="text" size="10" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$" title="Alphnumeric" required autofocus ng-model="selectedMember.Code.Staff_Type_Code">
                    <input type="text" size="10" hidden ng-model="selectedMember.sys_key" /> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Latin Description</td>
                <td><input type="text" required size="35" ng-model="selectedMember.Latin.L_Desc"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Local Description</td>
                <td><input type="text" required size="35" ng-model="selectedMember.Local.A_Desc"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>No. Of Houres Per Day</td>
                <td><input type="text" pattern="^[0-9]+$" title="Please enter numbers only" size="10" maxlength="2" ng-model="selectedMember.Hours_Day"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>No. Of Days Per Week(s)</td>
                <td><input type="text" pattern="^[0-9]+$" title="Please enter numbers only" size="10" maxlength="2" ng-model="selectedMember.Days_Week"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>End Of Contract By</td>
                <td>
                    <select>
                        <option ng-model="Age">Age</option>
                        <option ng-model="NYears">Number Of Years in Service</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Number</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" pattern="^[0-9]+$" title="Please enter numbers only" size="10" maxlength="2" ng-model="selectedMember.Num_EndWork">
                    <select>
                        <option ng-model="Months">Months</option>
                        <option ng-model="Years">Years</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </fieldset>

    <br />

    <table border="1" ng-hide="Hide">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <!--<th>syskey</th>-->
                <th>Code</th>
                <th>Latin Description</th>
                <th>Local Description</th>
                <th>Hours_Day</th>
                <th>Days_Week</th>
                <th>Num_EndWork</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="c in Contracts | filter:selectedMember.Code | filter:selectedMember.Latin | filter:selectedMember.Local ">

                <td style="display:none;"><a href="#" ng-click="showInEdit(c)">{{c.sys_key}}</a></td>
                <td><a href="#" ng-click="showInEdit(c)">{{c.Staff_Type_Code}}</a></td>
                <td><a href="#" ng-click="showInEdit(c)">{{c.L_Desc}}</a></td>
                <td><a href="#" ng-click="showInEdit(c)">{{c.A_Desc}}</a></td>
                <td><a href="#" ng-click="showInEdit(c)">{{c.Hours_Day}}</a></td>
                <td><a href="#" ng-click="showInEdit(c)">{{c.Days_Week}}</a></td>
                <td><a href="#" ng-click="showInEdit(c)">{{c.Num_EndWork}}</a></td>

            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</form>
```

Controller

```
contractT.controller('crudController', function ($scope, crudService)
{

loadrecords();
function loadrecords()
{    
        crudService.getContracts().then(function (response) {
            $scope.Contracts = (response.data);
            $scope.selectedMember = {};
        console.log($scope.Contracts);
    });
}

$scope.save = function () {

    debugger;
    var Contract = { Code: $scope.Staff_Type_Code, Latin: $scope.L_Desc, Local: $scope.A_Desc, Nend: $scope.Num_EndWork, Tend: $scope.Type_EndWork, hd: $scope.Hours_Day, dw: $scope.Days_Week }

    if ($scope.Type_EndWork == "Age" && $scope.Days_Month == "Months")
        $scope.Type_EndWork = 1
    else if ($scope.Type_EndWork == "Age" && $scope.Days_Month == "Years")
        $scope.Type_EndWork = 2
    else if ($scope.Type_EndWork == "NYears" && $scope.Days_Month == "Months")
        $scope.Type_EndWork = 3
    else ($scope.Type_EndWork == "NYears" && $scope.Days_Month == "Years")
    $scope.Type_EndWork = 4

    if ($scope.selectedMember.sys_key == {}) {
        var promisesave = crudService.post(Contract);
        promisesave.then(function (pl) {
            $scope.selectedMember = {};
            loadrecords();
        }, function (err) {
            console.log("Err" + err);
        });
    }
}

$scope.resetform = function () {
    $scope.selectedMember = {};
    //$scope.selectedMember = {};
    //$scope.Local = {};
    //$scope.Nhd = null;
    //$scope.Ndw = null;
    //$scope.Num = null;
    }




$scope.selectedMember = {  Code: "",sys_key:"", Latin:"" , Local:"", Hours_Day :"", Days_Week:"", Num_EndWork:""  } 

$scope.showInEdit = function (member)
{
    $scope.selectedMember = member;
    $scope.selectedMember.Code = member;
    $scope.selectedMember.Latin = member;
    $scope.selectedMember.Local = member;
    //$scope.selectedMember.Hours_Day = member;
    //$scope.selectedMember.Days_Week = member;
    //$scope.selectedMember.Num_EndWork = member;
}
```

the service is

```
this.post = function(Contract) {
    var request = $http({
        method: "post",
        url: "/ContractTypesAPI/api/ContractTypes/addContract",
        data: JSON.stringify(Contract),
        dataType: "json"
    });

};
```

Comment: The title and/or the tags should explain in what you want to insert something.

Comment: I made an edit and added the service part, the rest is web api is it ok

Comment: any help or idea to solve this problem

Comment: i am trying to insert into SQL database

Comment: any help for this issue